# How do I use the $ sign to a string to make it a variable?

Tags: php

I have made a small static test script for just explain what i want to do.

```
<?php
$test = "hello";
$demo = "php";
$x = array("hello"=>"world","php"=>"script");
echo $x[$test]."<br />";
echo $x[$demo];
?>
```

OUTPUT: world
        script

How could i get same output dynamically when values are come from database.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT font FROM stone");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $x[$row['font']]."<br/>";// values of $row['font'] are 'test' and demo
  }
```

Comment: Please do not use mysql. Use **mysqli** or **PDO** instead

Comment: Have you tried it? Didn't it work?

Comment: Well, it should. If `$test` is a string `'hello'` and `$row['font']` is a string `'hello'` then `$test === $row['font']` and `$x[$test] === $x[$row['font']]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$vars=get_defined_vars();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT font FROM stone");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $var=$vars[$row['font']];
  echo $x[$var]."<br/>";
}
//just for funny :)
//only :|
```

Comment: also we can use  echo $x[$$row['font']].